# How to put a Eureka form in a UIViewController together with another table?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I want to have something like this

```
class MyView: FormViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    // etc..
}
```

However i am not able to implement the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `numberOfRowsInSection` because they are already implemented within the Eurka library. I tried to overwrite those functions as well without success:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView.restorationIdentifier != "myTable" {
        return tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section)
    }
    return myDataType.count
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `UITable`. Why are you calling a view controller "MyView"? Look up `UITableViewDataSource` in the docs.

Comment: @Mundi perhaps someone implemented a custom `UITable` class

Comment: Prefixing it with "UI"? Looks more like sloppiness. Just out of interest: What's a good scenario to subclass `UITableView`??

Comment: Sorry was sloppiness with copying it here (Corrected it above). However that does not resolve my problem ;)

Comment: hi, did you get something?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you don't need to.  I tried the same thing, dragging a UITableViewController to the storyboard and setting its class to be my cub class of FormViewController.  This seems to have caused a bunch of issues, as FormViewController does a bunch of stuff already that may not be 100% workable with a standard UITableViewController.  So I removed it and used a UIViewController instead.

The UIViewController has a view property and the table view is a sub view of that.  This seems to work.

In my subclass, I just created the rows and sections using the eureka syntax, and did not set up my own table view or the delegate or the data source.  This allows the rows to appear properly with the tags and values that I set.

Look at the example app, a lot of the stuff is in there.

Not sure this technically answers your question, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I did what you are doing but somehow I needed to add a tableView to the ViewController AND set the delegate and dataSource, which I find really odd since (as you said) in the example app this is not needed, plus in my app I created my first view is a simple viewController with no TableView... (ps I was adding a new ViewController to my project)

Comment: ok I found my error, forgot to add the 'super.init' in 'ViewDidLoad'

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I came across a similar issue recently.

I would suggest using a container view and embed the FormViewController inside it.

This way you can have your table view in the parent UIViewController and access the form via the container. How to do that is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287161/get-child-view-from-containerview)