# Get child view from ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ViewController` with two overlapping `ContainerViews`.
[image]

But i didn't find method how in `RootViewController` get child from `ContainerView`.

Comment: Just wondering the need of two container views? which can be easily achieved by a single container view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In storyboard add identifier `MyEmbedSegueIdentifier` to your Embed Segue (from container to child view controller).
In root view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MyEmbedSegueIdentifier" {
        let childVC = segue.destinationViewController
    }
}
```